# Problems installing node.js/npm forever on Raspberry Pi

Tags: linux, node.js, npm, forever

Versions

```
Linux distro and version: Raspbian GNU/Linux 7 (wheezy)"
Python: 2.7.3
Nodejs: v0.10.22
NPM: 1.3.15
```

Every time I try to install forever globally on my Raspberry pi it fails.  The error is listed below.

```
sudo npm install forever -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/0.1.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/winston/0.7.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cliff/0.1.8
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/flatiron/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-monitor/1.2.3
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nconf/0.6.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/nssocket
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.4.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/0.3.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/timespan/2.0.1
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/watch/0.7.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/utile/0.1.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cliff/0.1.8
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/winston/0.7.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/colors/0.6.0-1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever-monitor/1.2.3
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nconf/0.6.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/nssocket
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.4.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/flatiron/0.3.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/pkginfo/0.3.0
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/timespan/2.0.1
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/watch/0.7.0
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/lazy
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/eventemitter2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/mkdirp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ncp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/rimraf
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/async
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/deep-equal
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/i
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/wordwrap
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/ps-tree
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/watch
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway/0.2.7
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.3.5
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.9
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/director/1.1.10
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/minimatch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/watch
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/broadway/0.2.7
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/optimist/0.3.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/prompt/0.2.9
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/director/1.1.10
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ps-tree
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/cliff/examples/put-rows-colors.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/cliff/examples/put-rows-colors.js
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/winston/test/log-rewriter-test.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/winston/test/log-rewriter-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/winston/test/log-rewriter-test.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Error: ENOENT, lstat '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/test/lines.js'
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/test/lines.js
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nssocket/node_modules/lazy/test/lines.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno 34
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:284:26
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! EEXIST, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf/stores'
File exists: /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf/stores
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf/stores
npm ERR! fstream_path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever/node_modules/nconf/lib/nconf/stores/file.js
npm ERR! fstream_type File
npm ERR! fstream_class FileWriter
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! errno 47
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js:171:23
npm ERR! fstream_stack /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js:37:53
npm ERR! fstream_stack Object.oncomplete (fs.js:107:15)
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected end of input
npm ERR! File: /root/.npm/broadway/0.2.7/package/package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! This is not a bug in npm.
npm ERR! Tell the package author to fix their package.json file. JSON.parse

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! file /root/.npm/broadway/0.2.7/package/package.json
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

similarly if I try to do this without sudo, I get the following:

```
npm install forever -g
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/forever
npm ERR! error rolling back Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever'
npm ERR! error rolling back  forever@0.10.9 { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever']
npm ERR! error rolling back   errno: 3,
npm ERR! error rolling back   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR! error rolling back   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever' }
npm ERR! Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever']
npm ERR!   errno: 3,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please try running this command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! System Linux 3.6.11+
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "forever" "-g"
npm ERR! cwd /home/pi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.22
npm ERR! npm -v 1.3.15
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno 3
npm ERR! stack Error: EACCES, unlink '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/forever'
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/pi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try installing node with [nvm](https://github.com/creationix/nvm). This installs node in your home directory so sudo permissions are not required for installing global modules.
It looks like the module you are installing is having issues with relative directories and it could help with not using sudo.

Comment: Would this solve the issue of installing globally? I need to run a command such as 'forever blah'

Comment: Yeah, that would. I can run all of my global modules under my user with no problem!

Answer (score 0):

Paths specified with a `.` are relative to the current working directory, not relative to the script file. So the file might be found if you run `node app.js` but not if you run `node folder/app.js`.

To make a path relative to the script, you must use the `__dirname` variable.

```
__dirname + '/path/to/file'
```

[Src](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file)