# Add user password during runtime

Tags: javascript, node.js, security

i've some node app which should get the user password to run ,
I dont want to put the user password hard-coded but I want some way to pass it during deployment, something like when I do 
`npm start` with the command line and add also user password which 
will be filled in the code, there is some best practice how to do it in node?

After I search in SO i've found this post but it's not helping since you put the code in config file which to me looks the same , the user passowrd is supplied with the code which I want to avoid...any example will be very helpful

[Best way to store DB config in Node.Js / Express app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348705/best-way-to-store-db-config-in-node-js-express-app)

Let's say one on the file need this user password for Runtime...

e.g.

```
request({
    uri: API,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    form: {
      'username': 'user123',
      'password': 'password123'
},
```

What I want is something similar to this approach , (or there something better which I want to understand how to use it)

```
 request({
    uri: API,
    method: 'POST',
    json: true,
    form: {
      'username': ~username,
      'password': ~password
},
```

And run the following command during deployment

`npm start username user123 password password123`

Comment: User password for what? What does the app do?

Comment: @Bergi- This code should run in the cloud and should provide user password to the cloud provider , but my question is for any user password which node app should provide and you want to provide it during deployment...

Comment: But what user are you talking about? The "user" who sets up the application on the server? The user(s) of the web application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can make use of *[environment variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable)*.**

Let's say you have an environment variable called `USERNAME`.
You can access it in your Node.js application like this:

```
console.log( process.env.USERNAME )
```

You can supply environment variables when starting your application like this:

```
USERNAME=example npm start
```

---

You may also want to check this supper cool project called **[dotenv](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)** which loads environment variables form a `.env` file.

You can add `.env` to your `.gitignore` and the credentials won't be shipped with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to have an external config file and read the username and password configuration from that. :) You will need to make sure that your web app doesn't serve the config file to the public either. So I would recommend putting the config into a higher level directory than your server so you would have less chance of accidentally serving your config.

Comment: oops It looks like you just edited your post :/ and now my answer isn't relavant.

Comment: This is the same approach I've provided in the link but im not sure this is the best way since as you write it can be accidentally provided ...

Comment: @JennyHilton as my previous comment said I see that my answer is now sort of irrelevant. I wrote my post just before you edited. :)

Comment: @JennyHilton The easiest way is to add a JSON file to your project with the configuration that is ignored by git/svn. Then combine `fs.readFile` and `JSON.parse` to read the stored password

Comment: @MarkNijboer You've hit the nail right on the head! That's exactly what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

I've build a similar app not so long ago. My folder structure was as follows:

```
root
|- app               // App logic (Not accessible in front-end)
|- templates         // Template files (Not accessible in front-end)
|- static            // Static files (Accessible in front-end)
|- config            // Config files (Not accessible in front-end)
   |- config.json    // Config file (Not accessible in front-end)
|- index.js          // Example JS file
```

if you add `config/config.json` to the .gitignore file, assuming you use git, it will not be transmitted when you push to production. This means that you have to make a config.json file in the production environment yourself that can hold different data than the development environment config.

Example config.json:

```
{
    "username" : "username1",
    "password" : "password123"
}
```

If you need the password in `index.js` you do the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./config/config.json', function(err, data) {
    if (!err) {
        const data = JSON.parse(data);
        const username = data.username;
        const password = data.password;

        // Use password here or store it in a local variable to use it later
    }
});
```