# Selenium WebDriver: Login to a website

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, e2e-testing

Is there a way to login to a website without writing the actual password in the code. For example, I created a function to login:

```
var isAlreadyLogIn = false;

function LogIn (userId, password) {
    if (!isAlreadyLogIn) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys(userId);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys(password);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@value='Login']")).click();
        isAlreadyLogIn = true;
    }
}

it('Should login', function(done) {
    LogIn("username", "password");
});
```

Comment: i quite didn't understand your question, is it that you don't want it be included in your code or anywhere (config files) at all in your project. due to security concerns ?

Comment: I don't want the password to be revealed anywhere in the code and preferably not in the config file either because of security concerns.

Comment: how about passing it through command line, when you run the code?

Answer (score 3):

Your code will need access to the credentials. I think the most common way to solve this is to put the credentials into a config file and read it from there.  If you don't want the passwords to be included with the code you can just not commit in the config-file to the repository, but share it with a different means. Alternatively you could pass the username and password as [command-line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22348985/1088584) to your tests.

[Here are NodeJS examples how to store the credentials in different ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22348705/best-way-to-store-db-config-in-node-js-express-app). The examples are for databases, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to use environment variables to store the username and password. This is what is recommended by SauceLabs. They have a best practices page that contains more details on how to create the environment variables, etc.

https://wiki.saucelabs.com/display/DOCS/Best+Practice%3A+Use+Environment+Variables+for+Authentication+Credentials

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, an option is using the profiles and the override system properties.

```
    <profile>
        <id>QA</id>
        <properties>
            <runUrl>http://qaenvironment.com </runUrl>
            <admin.username>admin</admin.username>
            <admin.password>adminpass</admin.password>          
            <noadmin.username>noadmin</noadmin.username>
            <noadmin.password>qwerty123</noadmin.password>
        </properties>
    </profile>
```

Runing the execution whit the QA profile, for example, and in the Java code using that:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Email']")).sendKeys(System.getProperty("admin.username"));
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Password']")).sendKeys(System.getProperty("admin.password"));
```