# npm error after installing node.js on the windows 8.1

Tags: windows, node.js

I have install `node-v0.10.31-x64` package on my windows 8.1. Then I have reboot my PC. After that I run the `node --version` command in the command line and get the output of `v0.10.31` but when I run the `npm install request cheerio` command I get the following error:

[image: error_Scr-shot]

What have i done wrong and how can I fix that?

Comment: does the folder exists ? if not, did you try to create it and check if your user is allowed to write into it.

Comment: Please check this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file

Comment: Did you try to run npm init?

Comment: @wut-globalitworld, the same output

Comment: Can you create new directory in c:\ instead this path and open cmd.exe cd c:\yourfoldername and try to run you command under your new folder again.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue when installing node.js on my Surface Pro 3 (Win 8.1).
My solution is as pAt and krampstudio suggested; create the folder and make sure permissions are set.

Steps for Win 8.1:

1. Open Explorer and navigate to your users folder.  (For you it would be:  C:\Users\Mykhaylo Vayvala)
2. Navigate to your AppData folder.  (This is hidden by default.  To reveal select "View" and check the option "Hidden Items" It should now appear.
3. Navigate to "Roaming" and create a folder called "npm"
4. Right click on the "npm" folder and select "properties", then uncheck the "Read only" attribute.
5. Click "ok"
6. Open a command prompt and now you should be able to execute "npm --version"

Hope that helps!

Comment: The problem with windows8.1 is, it does not add nodejs to "PATH" in environment variables. it only adds roaming/npm.
I manually added nodejs path "C:\Program Files\nodejs" to PATH and npm started working.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try creating npm folder in that path manually?