# Error: ENOENT, stat '/app/public/views/index.html' in Heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I'm having an error serving static views on a Heroku app. Strangely, Heroku seems to append "app" to the front of my static file paths, and I'm not sure why. The path should be "public/views/index.html."

I recently tried this proposed solution from Stack, but it didn't seem to work: [Node.js, can't open files. Error: ENOENT, stat './path/to/file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file)

The get requests from my server:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/index.html');
});

// profile page
app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
  // check for current (logged-in) user
  req.currentUser(function (err, user) {
    // show profile if logged-in user
    if (user) {
      res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/views/profile.html');
    // redirect if no user logged in
    } else {
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  });
});
```

Does anyone have any idea why Heroku would append "app" to my paths?

All the paths work correctly on a local server. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the global `__dirname` variable inside Heroku is set to `/app`. Use `process.env.PWD` instead of `__dirname`.

Answer (score 3):

The accepted. solution here of using `PWD` instead of `__dirname` is quite wrong. sendFile works on Heroku the same way it works anywhere else:

```
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'views', 'index.html'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this hasn't had an update in a while, but I ran into the same Heroku root directory confusion, but when I changed my code to use 'path' instead of __dirname, it worked.

```
path.join(__dirname, '..', 'views', 'email', `${template}.pug`),
```