# Heroku ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/index.html'

Tags: node.js, heroku

I'm having trouble running a simple test site in Heroku. For some reason  it's trying to serve the content from /app/build/ when I want it to serve from /build/.

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/index.html'

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527462/error-enoent-stat-app-public-views-index-html-in-heroku) not to use __dirname in the express app as Heroku set it to /app and that I should use process.cwd();

```
process.env.PWD = process.cwd();
```

But it didn't work. Below is my server.js express app and folder structure

```
const path = require('path');
const express = require('express');
const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const app = express();

process.env.PWD = process.cwd();

app.use(express.static(process.env.PWD + '/build'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  const index = path.join(process.env.PWD, '/build/index.html');
  res.sendFile(index);
});

app.listen(port);
console.log('server_started');
```

[image: directory structure]

Comment: instead of `process.env.PWD` did you tried to use `__dirname`, i have a site deployed with that

Comment: I tried that originally and it wasn't working. I found the link above which said _dirname is mapped to 'app' in heroku and to try process.cwd() but it's doing the same thing.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First, don't use PWD. Just use __dirname. It works on Heroku exactly as it works anywhere else. Using PWD makes your app more brittle if you, for instance, execute a binary from a non-local directory.

Second, the reason that file doesn't exist on Heroku is likely because you've added it to your .gitignore file or generally haven't checked it into git. You can see this from the color coding of your editor - all of the files checked into git are white, the ones ignored are gray (like the node_modules directory and build/bundle). Your index file is red (not white like the checked-in files). So when you `git push heroku master`, those files you're referencing don't exist.

Finally, the reason ENOENT says /app/build is just because your root/home directory on Heroku is /app. Never build apps that are locked into an absolute file structure; just use relative paths (otherwise, your app will break if you even move it to another directory on your local machine).

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  const index = path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html');
  res.sendFile(index);
});
```

Comment: I found my answer.  my .gitignore was ignoring the build folder. I feel such a fool. I accepted your answer as it's the most helpful to anyone else having similar issues. Many thanks :)

Comment: @screenm0nkey same problem here , plz add this comment as answer. this may helpful

Comment: For all those routing React apps through Express this answer will solve your basic redirection to a custom domain from the root path (' / ') -> (' /myRoute ').

Comment: @screenm0nkey same here ._. But actually, I didn't touch the default .gitignore created with react-create-app...

Answer (score 13):

*dist* folder is ignored. therefore heroku returns this error.
When you list your application files in heroku, you can see it is missing.

How to list folder/files in heroku

1. run *heroku run bash* in command line inside of your app folder
2. type *dir* and enter. then you will see the list of folders and files

Answer (score 4):

Check your package.json file

```
"postinstall": "ng build --aot --prod"
```

Check your server.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/dist/YOURPROJECTNAME'));
app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + '/dist/YOURPROJECTNAME/index.html'));

});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

Answer (score 3):

Note that it's a better practice to use `heroku-postbuild` command in your script rather than pushing the `build` folder.

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but I had set everything.
Heroku Post build inside my node package.json file.
See below

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "node index.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm run build"
}
```

- Was still getting the error
  Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat + app/client/build/index.html'

Just found out that this was happening because in my react folder index.js file
Please see below

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDom from 'react-dom'
import App from './App' #importing the App.js component

ReactDom.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root')) 
// render the react app
```

However I was not exporting my App.js component, hence, when I deployed to heroku the file was not being picked up.

Here is the line to export my App component

```
export default App;
```

- Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 3):

I also ran into this problem and finally I found the solution.

The mistake I did:
the reason that file doesn't exist on Heroku is likely because I've added it to .gitignore file i.e /build folder. So index.html was not checked-in to git.

Solution:
Just remove /build folder from .gitignore and it was **working finally**.

Answer (score 2):

Once you add the static file location with:

```
app.use(express.static('build'));
```

Express looks up the files relative to the static directory, so the name of the static directory is not part of the URL. You should be able to just do this to get index.html:

```
app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

See https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html

Answer (score 2):

I had similar issue where `Heroku open` kept on complaining for missing `index.html` inside `/app`. However it was working fine locally '`Heroku Local`'.

The issue was i had explicitly ignored compiled files/folder e.g. `/dist` in the `gitignore` file and hence `/dist` was never pushed onto the `heroku` deployed folder.

Do,

```
heroku git bash
dir
```

and ensure you have `dist folder (with compiled files)` listed here and all should be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with a React App deploy on a vps with dokku.

I ve fixed it with same as above BUT you need to `npm run build` in your terminal with `"scripts"` in you package.json like:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
  },
```

Then add the /build folder in your .gitignore.
Now delete the `"build": "react-scripts build",` before pushing on master (there is a conflit with `"heroku-postbuild"`).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Angular and node. It was because my dist folder was not included in the repo, either you change the .gitignore in your angular app, or copy the dist folder to another location. Then refer it form the server.js or app.js

Answer (score 0):

you create a folder with name app and put client folder on it
after that change directory path to

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  //static folder add
app.use(express.static('app/client/build'));
app.get("*", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname , "app/client/build", "index.html"));
});
}
```

add script to

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd app && cd client && npm install && npm run build"
 }
```

your problem is resolve