# Heroku Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/index.html'

Tags: heroku, deployment, feathersjs

I am getting this error in my heroku logs.

[Same Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535558/heroku-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-stat-app-build-index-html)

All the solutions provided here did not address the issue.

I tried the different variations of the get method:

```
app.use(express.static('build'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});
```

What else could I try or am I missing from here?

**App.js**

```
const configuration = require('@feathersjs/configuration');
const feathers      = require('@feathersjs/feathers');
const express       = require('@feathersjs/express');
const socketio      = require('@feathersjs/socketio');
const moment        = require('moment');

class IdeaService {
  constructor() {
    this.ideas = [];
  }

  async find() {
    return this.ideas;
  }

  async create(data) {
    const idea = {
      id: this.ideas.length,
      text: data.text,
      tech: data.tech,
      viewer: data.viewer
    };

    idea.time = moment().format('h:mm:ss a');

    this.ideas.push(idea);

    return idea;
  }
}

const app = express(feathers());

app.feathers().configure(configuration());

app.use(express.static('build'));

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile('index.html');
});

// Parse JSON

app.use(express.json());

// Configure SocketIO realtime API

app.configure(socketio());

// Enable REST services

app.configure(express.rest());

// Register services

app.use('/ideas', new IdeaService());

// Connect new streams

app.on('connection', conn => app.channel('stream').join(conn));

// Publish events to stream

app.publish(data => app.channel('stream'));

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3030;

app.listen(PORT).on('listening', () => console.log(`Server running on port ${PORT}`));

app.service('ideas').create({
  text: 'Build a cool app',
  tech: 'Node.js',
  viewer: 'John Doe'
});

export default IdeaService;
```

[image]

**package.json**

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about that, but this error seems to be related to the fact you are using an absolute path to this file, an absolute path that does not exist in your deployed application.

Comment: @EddeAlmeida where am I using the absolute path? The `index.html`?

Comment: Yes @and1. This file is being served by Heroku's server and the directory structure they use is different from yours. I've had errors like this using Heroku and had to use a routes.json file to point to the right file. https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/how-heroku-works