# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/backend/frontend/build/index.html'

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, heroku

i pushed my mern stack project to heroku master for deployement after opening the app its showing not found. spent so many hours and refered related stackoverflow questions nothing fixed my issue

**i build my project using**

```
    "scripts": {
        "build": "cd backend && npm install && cd ../frontend && npm install && npm run build",
        "start": "node backend/server.js",
}
```

inside terminal i build my project using `npm run build` build successfully

**server.js**

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build')));
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/frontend/build/index.html'))
})
```

**and here is my folder structure**

[image]

**files inside build folder**

[image]

pushing files to heroku master return successfull with no errors.
loging `heroku logs --tail` gives this below

```
2022-11-08T06:05:01.882420+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2022-11-08T06:05:09.142138+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `npm start`
2022-11-08T06:05:11.262904+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-11-08T06:05:11.262931+00:00 app[web.1]: > blog-app@1.0.0 start
2022-11-08T06:05:11.262932+00:00 app[web.1]: > node backend/server.js
2022-11-08T06:05:11.262932+00:00 app[web.1]:
2022-11-08T06:05:11.880253+00:00 app[web.1]: server connected on port http://localhost:52809
2022-11-08T06:05:12.097847+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2022-11-08T06:05:13.711620+00:00 app[web.1]: server connected to mongoDB
2022-11-08T06:05:23.749281+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thekrishblog.herokuapp.com request_id=f8b42c26-5f03-46e5-a04e-0fa6cb14d8b8 fwd="117.204.133.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2022-11-08T06:05:23.750032+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/backend/frontend/build/index.html'     
2022-11-08T06:06:26.010343+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=thekrishblog.herokuapp.com request_id=18800012-c573-49aa-a6f8-b107f95a3013 fwd="117.204.133.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=2ms status=404 bytes=380 protocol=https
2022-11-08T06:06:26.008479+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/backend/frontend/build/index.html'
```

also refered [Heroku ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/build/index.html'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535558/heroku-enoent-no-such-file-or-directory-stat-app-build-index-html) but it dosent answered my problem

Comment: Might be good to show inside the build folder, so that we can see, where the index.html file is.

Comment: @Geshode ok, just take a look at question again. updated my question and added build folder image also

Comment: How do you resolve the probem?

Answer (score 1):

I identify two problems
Please try one after another to check if are both the case:

**1.)** In your error message I see: `/backend/frontend/build/index.html` but it should be

`frontend/build/index.html`. To fix that adjust the path to:

```
 if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/build')));

  app.get('*', (req, res) =>
    res.sendFile(
      path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'frontend', 'build', 'index.html')
    )
  );
} else {
  app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.send('200');
  });
}
```

**2.)** Check if

> /app

`'/app/backend/frontend/build/index.html'`

it's not too much. I assume that you adjust the **root path** on your hoster to `'app'`
but that not necessary.