# Winston logger throws ENOENT

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, winston, enoent

My Code:

```
import winston from 'winston';

Meteor.startup(() => {
  const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
  const tsFormat = () => (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString();
  const logDir = 'log';
  const logger1 = new (winston.Logger)({
    transports: [
      // colorize the output to the console
      new (winston.transports.Console)({
        timestamp: tsFormat,
        colorize: true,
        level: 'info',
      }),
      new (winston.transports.File)({
        filename: `${logDir}/results.log`,
        timestamp: tsFormat,
        level: env === 'development' ? 'debug' : 'info',
      }),
    ],
  });
  logger1.info('Hello world');
  //logger1.warn('Warning message');
  //logger1.debug('Debugging info');
});
```

Output:

```
I20170717-11:39:11.027(2)? 11:39:10 - info: Hello world
W20170717-11:39:11.150(2)? (STDERR)
W20170717-11:39:11.151(2)? (STDERR) events.js:72
W20170717-11:39:11.152(2)? (STDERR)         throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
W20170717-11:39:11.152(2)? (STDERR)               ^
W20170717-11:39:11.153(2)? (STDERR) Error: ENOENT, open 'log/results.log'
```

The results.log is not even created

**Update:** When i use only a filename without a path then it works).

Related but not helped solving:
[Node.js, can't open files. Error: ENOENT, stat './path/to/file'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file)

What is the problem?

Comment: try checking directory chmod, or manually create the file, etc. Does something change?

Comment: Does the `log` directory exist?

Comment: @robertklep nope

Comment: Winston won't create it for you.

Comment: @robertklep you can add it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Winston doesn't actually create the directory where you want the logfile to go, which is why you get the `ENOENT`.

(I'm not very familiar with Meteor, but the following instructions work on "plain" Node.js)

You can create the directory manually before instantiating Winston to make sure it exists, using [`fs.mkdirSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_mkdirsync_path_mode), although that would only go one level deep (it won't create intermediate directories, if there are any in the path).

There's also [`mkdirp.sync()`](https://github.com/substack/node-mkdirp), which *does* create intermediate directories.

Using the synchronous versions is a bit easier, and since it's an operation that only occurs once during the start of the app, it's not a bottleneck.