# ionic serve not compiling typescript

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

I started working on this project on my home PC on Windows 10 using the latest version of Ionic CLI and Typescript and `ionic serve` works perfectly there.

However after cloning the exact same project to my work PC with Ubuntu which is also running the latest version of Ionic, I get this error when I try to use ionic serve:

`"www" directory cannot be found. Please make sure the working directory is an Ionic project.`

So obviously now on this PC it's not compiling the Typescript before running it. Somehow on my work PC it thinks this is a plain JS project?

Comment: Have you moved to the root of the Ionic project before calling the `Ionic serve`?

Comment: @Sampath Yes, I'm in the root of the project where the package.json is. I also did run `npm install` after cloning it.

Comment: do you have .editorconfig file in the root?

Comment: @mohamadrabee Yes I do, and I'm using Webstorm on both PCs if that matters.

Comment: do you have a file `ionic.project` in your root?

Comment: @mohamadrabee No but I do have `ionic.config.json`

Comment: try to update the cli by running `npm install -g ionic@latest`

Comment: @mohamadrabee Did that several times, I even did `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic && sudo npm install -g ionic@latest`. Still the same issue.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a '!' character somewhere in path to project? I had similar problem when using something like /!jobs/projects for my ionic root, and when I moved it to path with no exclamation mark, everything suddenly worked. Took me 2 days to figure that out... HTH

Comment: just create an empty www folder. and give that a try. I had that on a project recently too

Comment: @JGFMK Thanks for the suggestion, I will try that when I'm at the office again tomorrow.

Comment: I saw it mentioned in a Github issues page somewhere. Can't recall now - was about 2-3 weeks ago. And it worked a treat in my case

Comment: @JGFMK Well, that got it to start up the server, but when I go to the address I get this error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/chris/WebstormProjects/ion-trader-mobile/www/index.html'`, and the www folder is empty.

Comment: That normally infers node/npm permission issues...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file