# Ionic CLI not uninstalling

Tags: ionic2, ionic3

This is related to my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45804412/ionic-serve-not-compiling-typescript) which was never resolved. I am trying to fix the problem by doing a fresh reinstall of Ionic.

I first tried uninstalling Ionic with `sudo npm uninstall -g ionic`, and it completes with no errors, but doing `ionic -v` still outputs `2.1.1`, so obviously it didn't really get uninstalled. After that I tried `sudo npm install -g ionic@latest`, and my problem still persists.

What is even weirder is what happened when I tried to create a new project from scratch to test it. I did `ionic start test --v2` on my Ubuntu machine, and doing `ionic serve` still does the same thing that I stated in my previous question.

Comment: did you try to reinstall NodeJS ?

Comment: @MahmoodSanjrani Just tried uninstalling and reinstalling nodejs and npm. Then I uninstalled Ionic and still, even before reinstalling Ionic again `ionic -v` still outputs 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your node and npm versions ?

Please update latest node js  (**https://nodejs.org/en/download/current/)**
then check that

```
 node -v  
 npm -v
```

Node version must be   v8.5.0 (includes npm 5.3.0) and then

```
 sudo npm uninstall -g ionic 
 sudo npm cache clean --force
 sudo npm install ionic
```

check the ionic version

```
ionic -v
```

version will be `^3.10.1`. If everything is ok you can use new project command as given below

```
ionic start --list
```

you can see what kind of project types here as an example

```
ionic start blank
```

Comment: Okay so I was on nodejs 7. I updated to 8.5 and uninstalled ionic again and I can still run `ionic -v` and get 2.1.1. I tried the cache clean and installing ionic again anyway and still getting 2.1.1.

Comment: it does not make sense.

Comment: I know, I've been fighting with this problem for weeks. It makes no sense at all. It sounds more like an Ubuntu system issue. I'll probably put this on Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 13):

> npm uninstall -g ionic

> npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli

finally i was able to uninstall with this...

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue for resolving this

1. Run **npm uninstall -g ionic**
2. Go to the location "**/usr/local/bin/**"
3. Delete Ionic File
4. Close terminal
5. Open new terminal and run "**npm uninstall -g ionic"**
6. Now run "**ionic -v**"

Answer (score 2):

This probably happens due to multiple installations of ionic in your machine, more so this happens on windows.
Run:
"where ionic" in your command prompt

if it does not work try :

"which ionic"  !! (probably linux)

This will give you the location of your installed ionic, in windows its mostly ..Local\AppData\Roaming..  somewhere.

Go to that location delete ionic and ionic.cmd file there.

Run:  ionic -v now, make sure it gives you an error.

Be Happy if you see error.

run: npm install ionic@latest -g now

Run: ionic -v, make sure you see your latest ionic version there.

Be more happy now.

Answer (score 2):

Uninstall cordova and ionic.

```
npm uninstall -g cordova
npm uninstall -g ionic
```

Then check to make sure you have the right version:

```
ionic -v
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this command please

```
npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try running the command as below, it worked for me:

```sh
sudo npm uninstall -g @ionic/cli
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are checking the ionic version inside project folder then 
try to remove the ionic cli without `-g` option. It may be possible that you have installed local version of ionic inside project.

Comment: Nope, still does the same thing outside the project directory.

Comment: have you tried to uninstall the ionic without sudo? It may be possible that two ionic cli have been installed : one for local user and another for sudo user.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using nvm, remember to delete ionic from `where ionic`. I deleted it via `nvm uninstall {{version}}`.

[image]