# pug.compileFile('./views/transactions/html.pug'); Heroku Node Express. Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, pug, nodemailer

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open './views/transactions/html.pug'
```

Running my application locally I don't have a problem, once I push to Heroku I get the above error. Locally I am using nodemon to serve my express server. I'm using pug to compile some html to send emails. This is the function that is causing the problem.

```
  pug.compileFile('./views/transactions/html.pug')
```

Using node Express, with React, serving the static/build files from the same server. 
[image: File Structure]

My suspicion is that I need to serve the 'views' directory as when I am running locally my nodemon will be doing this, however, I 'm not sure how to do this.

This is a view of my server.js file[image].

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution to the error message. I got this from this post [about node/heroku filepaths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file?noredirect=1&lq=1).

The issue was that locally my file path was pointing to the correct file but the online/heroku server needed a different filepath. I have included a picture of the file structure for what it's worth.

```
function createEmailFilePath(filename) {
  const newpath = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 
    path.resolve('emails', 'transactions', filename) : 
    path.resolve('..', 'emails', 'transactions', filename);
    return newpath;
}
```

[image]