# File not found when using elastic beanstalk

Tags: mean-stack, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, google-calendar-api

I created this mean stack app and have deployed it to aws elastic bean stalk.  Everything is working fine except the google calendar api client secret.  I've attached a picture so you can see my file structure and how I was trying to access the client secret json file[image]

In the bean stalk logs I am receiving the following errors:

> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '../client_secret.json'
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   '/backend/client_secret.json'
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open
>   'backend/client_secret.json'

In the code this is what I have tried:

```
  try {
const content = fs.readFileSync('../client_secret.json');
authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvents);
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  }

  try {
const content = fs.readFileSync('/backend/client_secret.json');
authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvents);
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  }

  try {
const content = fs.readFileSync('backend/client_secret.json');
authorize(JSON.parse(content), insertEvents);
  } catch (err) {
    return console.log('Error loading client secret file:', err);
  }
```

Thanks  I know something small that I've missed but been fiddling with this for a while now

Answer (score 0):

Started with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541948/node-js-cant-open-files-error-enoent-stat-path-to-file) article didnt know needed to add path.join(__dirname, 'file location')